# How do you decode a returned JSON array in php function

Tags: php, json

I have two php functions, one returns a JSON array and the other attempts to decode it and access it's contents in order to strip a URL out of it.  My problem is that I get the following errors..

1) json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string

2) Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 77

Here is my code

php file 1

```
<?php

function getAnimation($userid, $db) {

    include('connect.php');

    $db = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "please contact d.g.folksman@ljmu.ac.uk for technical assistance";
        echo "<br>";
    }

    $box_num = 1;

    $select = "SELECT card_id, order_num FROM decks WHERE box_num=$box_num AND id=$userid ORDER BY order_num";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $select) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysqli_error($db));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $users[] = array(
            'card_id' => $row['card_id'],
            'order_num' => $row['order_num'],
        );
    }

    json_encode($users);

    return $users;

    mysqli_close($db);
}

?>
```

snippet of php file 2 that is attempting to decode the JSON array and access its contents.

```
include('getAnimation.php');
$animation = getAnimation($result_array[0], $db); //<< atempting to access returned array here
$obj = json_decode($animation);  //FIRST ERROR HERE
foreach ($obj->card_id as $item) { // SECOND ERROR HERE
$url = ($item->card_id);
echo $url; //show me the money
}
```

thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the `return` to be `return json_encode($users)`. You're not actually setting the variable `$users`... you could also set it with `$users = json_encode($users)`, then return `$users`.

To answer your second question, modify your code as such:

```
foreach($obj as $item) {
    $url = $item->card_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I don;t quite understand whats going on here.  COuld you elaborate a bit for me.

Comment: Sure- after you create your array with your function and `json_decode` it, you'll have an array of objects that you then just want to walk through (`foreach`) and access their properties (`card_id`, in this case)!

Comment: Just as an added thought, if i wanted to store the contents of the JSON array in an array, would I have to do something like.. `foreach ($obj as $item) {
                $url[$i] = $item->card_id;
                $i++;
                echo $url[$i];
            }`

Comment: Doesn't look like `$i` would point to anything in that case... you'd have to do `foreach ($obj as $i => $item) {  }` if you wanted to access the keys.

Answer (score 1):

**json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string**

`json_encode()` returns a value, it doesn't act on the parameter by reference, so when you have:

```
json_encode($users);

return $users;
```

you're returning the original array, and not the JSON representation.

Fix it by doing:

```
return json_encode($users);
```

**Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 77**

You encode an array, so you should be decoding an array - so you should be looping over the array, not an object:

```
foreach ($obj->card_id as $item)
```

should just be:

```
foreach ($obj as $item) {
    $url = $item["card_id"];
    echo $url;
}
```

**Side note**

Avoid using generic variables names like $obj and $item - they are not descriptive, and PHP can have some unusual scoping quirks, especially if you are using buffering.

Comment: THanks, that fixed the first error, but I still get the second error.  Any ideas?

Comment: sry - didn't read past the first error, as I thought the second was caused by the first. have addressed that now

Comment: Thanks for that answer it was very good, but I had already given best answer.  Just as an added thought, if i wanted to store the contents of the JSON array in an array, would I have to do something like.. `foreach ($obj as $item) {
                $url[$i] = $item->card_id;
                $i++;
                echo $url[$i];
            }`

Comment: well, once you've decoded the JSON string into a variable, it will be an array...

Comment: Oh right :) I thought you had to assign it to a php array to access its members.  I want to pass each url to a javascript function in the same page.  Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
json_encode($users);
return $users;
```

to:

```
$users = json_encode($users);
return $users;
```

That's it! :-)